# iMac as a print server for iOS?

Tags: printing

We have an older-ish network laser printer which unfortunately doesn't support Airprint (previously mentioned) and have been looking for ways to enable our family of iOS devices to print from it.

The best idea I've come up with so far is to purchase an iMac (planned anyway) and physically connect the printer to it - would the iMac then be able to act as a print server for, say, an iPad? I have used print sharing in the past but am unclear as to whether it supports iOS (although it would make sense for it to).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an app, like [Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/) running continuously on a logged in Mac.

Comment: So the standard print sharing built into OSX will not do the job?

Comment: No it will not. Printopia is about $10 and well worth it.

Comment: There is a free app, AirPrint Activator http://netputing.com/airprintactivator/airprint-activator-v2-0/ that works reasonably well too.